# cannot do typeconversion in typescript using the angle-bracket syntax

Tags: typescript

Ok, Here we go:

`this.currentRecID` is defined to be as a number.

Given that, at some point in code, you must check this:

```
if  (this.currentRecID === '0' ) {}
```

But, typescript does not let you do  `if  (this.currentRecID === '0' ) {}` for reasons I understand; `this.currentRecID`'s variable type is number so it is understandable for it to not to tolerate the '0' shit.

Then you think of deploying the Type Assertion - cause you expect for it to be handy in situations like this. With that in mind,  you go like this;

```
  if ( <string>this.currentRecID === '0'  ) {}
```

But in no time, you get stopped by this lovely message:

`[ts] Type 'number' cannot be converted to type 'string'.`

Any way out of this? How would you get the time when this.currentRecID is really '0'?

Comment: `<any>this.currentRecID === '0'`

Comment: Nice! It is so much better than mine:  `let tempCurrentRecID: any; tempCurrentRecID = this.currentRecID  + ''; if ( tempCurrentRecID === '0'  )  {} ` attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to make sure you variable is a string or number of whatever it is usually done like this

```
if (typeof this.currentRecID === 'number') {
 // this.currentRecID would be of type number inside this block
}
```

But it looks like you are not sanitazing input of user or rest api or something like that, otherwise how can the variable of type number become string? It is especially odd to check for var type on class members. Any untrusted sources of data should be validated somehow beforehand

Comment: That's another way to solve the problem. But I would still expect what's called Type Assertion ( the <string> that is ) to do what it's supposed to do. Cartant's and your solutions, (like my own one ) are simply workarounds.

Comment: hi! jsut want to mention that type assertion is an escape hatch for rare situations when you as a developer know about the variable type better then the typescript, mostly due to the limited type inferring system of typescript (e.g. you did some complex operations on objects or arrays). Of couse it can be used the way shown on your post, but if feel like something have gone wrong before.. So the question is why do you expect to have '0' instead of 0 in the first place

Comment: I totally get what you are saying and agree with you on all counts. typically. Here is my story though. You want to define ID as a number. But when you parse an ID from a query string or from another string, you just end up with a string. It's just the way it is. Well at some point, you got to those comparsisons. That's the situation I found myself into. I still think there is something buggy about the <string> works in the TypeScript.( I find it odd for `<string>myNumber` would not work but `'' + myNumber` works on the same linter. )

Comment: yeah I see. maybe it would be worth it to parse the id with parseInt before assigning it to the class member. for more complex types (e.g. rest json returns and so on) `json schema` parsers or validators like `joi` could be used  as type guards (functions returning `x is MyType`) to make sure the data matches the type or interface, than it all becomes very typesafe. Regarding the `'' + myNumber` example, I think it works because the '+' implies that non-string variables will be appended with `.toString()` implicitly (for instance this also works well: `const z = '123' + { x: 1 };`). Good Luck!

Comment: Great info. Lots of pointers... Thank you and have a happy new year!